# NPN Transistors Not Working When Emitter Is Grounded

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn

I'm trying out transistor logic for the first time using PN2222 transistors that came in a kit that I got from Amazon.  I've been running into some problems with making a basic NOT Gate (as shown in the schematic below) and I haven't been able to complete it.

I believe that I have faulty transistors, but so far I've tried them all (as well as troubleshooting with a meter, checking for continuity, and changing all components for new ones) and have come to the same outcome every time.

## Schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkXwWn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

## The Problem

When I put my LED on the collector-side of my BJT with a resistor hooked to +5V without anything attached to the BJT's base or emitter I get what I expect, the LED lights up as the rest of the BJT has nothing to do with that LED circuit. **However the moment I attach the emitter to ground, the LED shuts off.**  Applying any kind of input (logic high or low) provides no change.

I tried to connect an LED from the emitter pin to ground, replacing the wire I had used previously, and I found that the collector LED stays lit and the emitter LED is on, but barely.

I can provide pictures of my breadboard circuit if need be.  Any help and advice is appreciated as I did say this is the first time I've messed around with REAL transistors, not ideal or simulated ones!

## Update (Edit)

R = 1k ohm, R2 = 220 ohm
Here are some pictures of my circuit:

(sorry for the bad quality, my camera is terrible and the LED is quite bright)

The top two photos are of the emitter being directly grounded, the next two are with an LED connecting the emitter to ground.  The first picture of both sets are with the switch off, then the second pics of both sets are with the switch pressed.

[image: Emitter grounded, switch off]

[image: Emitter grounded, switch on]

Notice that the LED connected to the emitter and ground lights up a little bit.

[image: LED connecting emitter and ground, switch off]

[image: LED connecting emitter and ground, switch on]

Comment: I think you are mistaking an open collector output stage which is for low current, voltage signals for a BJT as a power switch for high currents. Your BJT is acting as a switch that lets current bypass the LED completely. LED should be in series with R2 for it to act as a switch for LED current.

Comment: @DKNguyen The kit probably really does use this circuit as a NOT gate. It's just that the OP misunderstands and thinks that sticking an LED to ground at the output will make the output visible and doesn't understand that the output may need buffering with an appropriate driver circuit for the LED in order to properly visualize the output-input relationship. Maybe. I don't know for sure. But that's what I'm imagining, now.

Comment: @DKNguyen I am attempting to follow along with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTu3LwpF6XI  It is by Ben Eater where in the video he makes logic gates using transistors.  Hope this helps!  Also I am uploading pics of my circuit shortly.

Comment: @EmirCurtovic In the last two photographs, I see **two** LEDs hooked up. Can you explain why?

Comment: Exactly how did you "apply a logic low" to the input? Based on your circuit the base of the BJT is either a) driven high or b) floating (left as an open circuit). When it's floating leakage currents may be causing it to conduct anyway. Try attaching a resistor to ground -- for example a 100k resistor to ground, attached to the point where R and the switch meet.

Comment: @jonk I wanted to see what would come of attaching an LED instead of just a wire to ground from the emitter.  Something else happened than I had expected, not sure of the answer it gives as I am just a beginner.  I was sure that would mean something more to someone more experienced than I am.

Comment: @EmirCurtovic So you are just *hacking around* a bit to see what happens. I get that. And it's fine. But.. it really complicates a good answer. What you need is a short chapter on the subject of BJT switch design, LED operation requirements and resistive current limiting, and a few design rules and assumptions. The subject isn't too difficult to cover with a short chapter. But the scope is still a bit daunting for this site. There are good books on the topic. (HP's "Optoelectronics: Fiber-Optics Applications Manual," 2nd edition.) I'm not sure I want to replicate the work they did.

Comment: @EmirCurtovic I think you need enough knowledge so that you not only can design something, but so that you can work out on your own why something you try does NOT work, as well. Knowing how to do both given all the varieties of ways you might "hunt and peck" out a circuit, even in something as simple in concept as this, takes a certain level of knowledge and experience. Your question is really a very broad one, now that I understand all the ways you are attempting to "see" what happens. You could narrow it down a bit (by NOT using two LEDs -- ever!)

Comment: @jonk Thank you for the input!  I will take this information and run with it!  I have some digital and analog circuit experience from my education in university, but I am very excited, possibly too excited, to try to work with transistors and transistor logic and amplification.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub I could be using the terminology wrong?  I thought low was represented by a 0 and high was represented by a 1 if i'm not mistaken?  I may have just been using the word logic wrong in there, but I am trying to make a very basic logic gate (NOT gate, of course).  Also I tried attaching different resistors between ground and the emitter and I found that the lower I go, the closer it gets to having a wire there and the higher it goes the circuit becomes more of a switch than a NOT gate.

Comment: @EmirCurtovic sure you're correct about 0 and 1, but what I mean is are you actually "driving" a logic zero (pulling the transistor base to ground). Based on your circuit diagram it looks like you're driving a logic 1 (by pulling the base high) but your logic zero is just a floating input, which could be trouble. BTW, note that I'm talking about the transistor **base** here (the terminal that's connected to resistor R), and you are mentioning the **emitter** (the terminal that's connected to ground in your diagram). Is the terminology maybe getting mixed up along the way...?

Comment: @Mr.Snrub Thanks for lettin me know!  I misread the heck out of your response when I read it the first time, that's on me!  Well regardless, I put a 100k resistor between the switch and resistor R (to ground as specified), but the same thing happens.  It should be noted that: When I checked for continuity and for any current or voltage from the 5v rail to the bjt I found nothing, the problem occurs when there is nothing connected to the base whatsoever as well, and that this happens with all my PN2222 transistors.

Comment: Try rotating the transistor 180°. There are some made with similar part numbers that are C-B-E rather than E-B-C.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany unfortunately I already tried this to no avail :(  thank you for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own issue by buying different transistors. All 5 PN2222 NPN transistors I got are apparently faulty.

I purchased [a small electronics starter kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D3S443Y) on Amazon as it was a Prime Day deal and it seemed like a steal at the time. However, the transistors I received were all faulty out-of-the-box.  In addition, some other components included in the kit have been noted to not work here and there (bad quality control, I guess ¯(°_o)/¯ ).

Please learn from my shopping mistake and buy a better kit elsewhere.

Comment: Faulty, or... perhaps the pinout  is E C B instead of  E B C ?

Comment: Woah! Been a year since this post! Regardless, I wanna say it was not switched around, the PN2222's were just bad, have done a lot of work with transistors and semiconductors since this post and I can easily say that with confidence as I tested this thought before I posted my answer.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. However I got a similar effect by swapping the Collector and Base. I suspect your transistors were incorrectly marked. Some 'equivalents' (eg. BC639) have the Collector in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a resistor between base - emitter to properly bias the transistor when switch is open. Floating base is a bad way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on floating base!  Despite this, however, my problem still persists.